# Removed gem, rails is now looking for "ghost" attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hey I installed them gem ActsAsTaggleOn, but couldn't get it to work probably so I removed it again. Now whenever I run db:setup I get an error

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: taggable_type
```

Which is an attribute that is used in the gem. Why is this still showing up? I have scanned my app for references to the attribute, but has found any. Any advice?

EDIT: I manually removed the migration files/changed the schema, maybe that has something to do with the error?

Comment: just guessing, try to roll back before deleted migration and then run db:migrate

Comment: I have no migrations, deleted them all

Comment: any git/svn repo ? this will be hard :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually removing migration files is a really bad idea if you already ran the migration. You can only remove the migration if you did a rollback first. If possible, you want to restore the manually deleted migration, rollback and then remove it. This will automatically update your schema.

If you have no clue how to restore the lost migration and you don't mind loosing data in your database you should run 'rake db:reset'. If necessary you can migrate up to the last working migration. For example, if your migrations are really fucked up you can run 'rake db:drop' and 'rake db:migrate VERSION=XXX' to drop your database and build it up again up to the last working migration.